# How can I access properties in objects contained in an array - see code

Tags: php, arrays, oop

How can I access properties in objects contained in an array?

Why does the code below doesn't work?

```
<?php

class Car{
    private $model;
    private $color;
    private $price;
    public function __car($model, $color, $price)
    {
        this.$model = $model;
        this.$color = $color;
        this.$price = $price;
    }
}

$cars = [];
$jetta = new Car("Jetta", "Red", 2500);
$cars[] = $jetta;

$cobalt = new Car("Cobalt", "Blue", 3000);
$cars[] = $cobalt;

// this is the part of the code that doesn't work
// I need to output the values from the objects, model, color and price
echo $cars[0]->$model; 
echo $cars[0]->$color;
echo $cars[0]->$price;
```

Thanks

Comment: Go look up what `private` visibility means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax and constructor is wrong.

Here is the final code:

```
<?php

class Car{
    // the variables should be public
    public $model;
    public $color;
    public $price;
    // this is how you write a constructor
    public function __construct($model, $color, $price)
    {
        // this is how you set instance variables
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->color = $color;
        $this->price = $price;
    }
}

$cars = [];
$jetta = new Car("Jetta", "Red", 2500);
$cars[] = $jetta;

$cobalt = new Car("Cobalt", "Blue", 3000);
$cars[] = $cobalt;

// this is how you access variables
echo $cars[0]->model; 
echo $cars[0]->color;
echo $cars[0]->price;

?>
```

Comment: Whoever has down voted, please check the answer again.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple errors in your code, I have pointed them with arrows `◄■■■` :

```
<?php

class Car{
    public $model;   //◄■■■■■■■■■■ IF PRIVATE YOU WILL NOT
    public $color;   //◄■■■■■■■■■■ BE ABLE TO ACCESS THEM
    public $price;   //◄■■■■■■■■■■ FROM OUTSIDE.
    public function __construct ($model, $color, $price) //◄■■■ CONSTRUCT
    {
        $this->model = $model;   //◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ NOT THIS.$
        $this->color = $color;   //◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ NOT THIS.$
        $this->price = $price;   //◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ NOT THIS.$
    }
}

$cars = [];
$jetta = new Car("Jetta", "Red", 2500);
$cars[] = $jetta;

$cobalt = new Car("Cobalt", "Blue", 3000);
$cars[] = $cobalt;

// this is the part of the code that doesn't work
// I need to output the values from the objects, model, color and price
echo $cars[0]->model;   //◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ PUBLIC PROPERTY WITHOUT $.
echo $cars[0]->color;   //◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ PUBLIC PROPERTY WITHOUT $.
echo $cars[0]->price;   //◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ PUBLIC PROPERTY WITHOUT $.
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation-comments, that helps.